# Using Powershell to identify all files modified by a program

Tags: powershell

I am looking to find a way to list all files modified by a program following an action in the program.  My thought process for this script is:

1. Take a snapshot of all objects on the H:\ drive.
2. Pause the script and go out to the program I am testing and take an action that will modify one or multiple files on the H:\ drive.
3. Take a second snapshot of the H:\ drive and output only files that have a different last modified time.

I already have a running script that will examine all files modified within the last hour but I wanted to set up a script that was more or less real time.

So far I have

```
$before = get-childitem H:\ -recurse
read-host
$after = get-childitem H:\ -recurse
Compare-object -referenceobject $before -differenceobject $after -Property lastwritetime -passThru | 
out-host
powershell -noexit
```

I am only getting a return on the first sub directory (alphabetically) that has been modified.  I am not getting a return on any other sub directories or files.

Comment: As it turns out this script was working as I intended.  The actions I was taking in the program were not changing the write time on those files.  Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) .NET type to monitor the directory.  You should be able to use the `Register-ObjectEvent` command to hook the `Changed` event and process the directory only when something has changed.